# Existence of small extensions

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-representations

Let $\mathsf{CNL}$ be the category of complete noetherian local rings with (fixed) residue field $\mathbb{F}$. The morphisms are local homomorphisms fixing the residue field. The full subcategory of artinian objects (i,e, artinian complete local rings residue field $\mathbb{F}$) is denoted by $\mathsf{Ar}$.

A homomorphism $f: A \rightarrow B$ in $\mathsf{Ar}$ is called a **small extension** or **small homomorphism**, if $f$ is surjective and its kernel $\ker f = (t)$ is a principal ideal, which is annihilated by $\mathfrak{m}_A$, the maximal ideal of $A$. (i.e. $\mathfrak{m}_A (t) = (0)$.)

Given such a small extension, we can obtain an exact sequence
$$
0 \rightarrow tA \rightarrow A \xrightarrow{f} B \rightarrow 0.
$$

**My Question 1: How to prove (or disprove) the following claim: For ANY object $A$ in $\mathsf{Ar}$, there exists a small extension $f: A \rightarrow A_0$ for some $A_0 \in \mathsf{Ar}$ with $\ell(A) > \ell(A_0)$**, where $\ell(R)$ is the length of the artinian ring $R$.

**Motivation**: The claim is used in proofs by induction in many contexts, such as the Appendix A on Page 106 of [this one](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=E78D0A0B18BF4A45DF0815EEFB85C713?doi=10.1.1.227.1721&rep=rep1&type=pdf) : *Galois Deformations and Hecke Curves* by B. Mazur.

**My question 2: Does every surjective homomorphisms in $\mathsf{Ar}$ factors as the composition of small homomorphisms?** I think this is related to the construction of Question 1 but not sure about this.

Thank you all for anwering or commenting this post and sorry for any mistakes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 1: the only restriction seems to be that $A \neq \mathbb{F}$. $A$ is artinian, so, if $\mathfrak{m}$ is its maximal ideal, there is a minimal integer $p \geq 2$ such that $\mathfrak{m}^p=\{0\}$. Take some nonzero $t \in \mathfrak{m}^{p-1}$ and define $A_0=A/tA$.

---

Question 2 asserts that any local surjection $s: A \rightarrow B$ of complete Noetherian Artinian local rings with residue field $F$ is a product of small extensions.

So consider such a surjection $s: A \rightarrow B$. Let’s show that if $s$ isn’t an isomorphism, then it factors through a small extension $A \rightarrow C$. Indeed, let $I$ be the kernel of $s$, and let $t \in I$ be nonzero (else it’s an empty product). There is $p \geq 1$ minimal such that $t\mathfrak{m}^p=\{0\}$, so choose $q \in t\mathfrak{m}^{p-1}$ nonzero and take $C=A/(q)$.

Now, repeating this with $C \rightarrow B$, we know that there is a sequence of small extensions $A \rightarrow C_1 \rightarrow C_2 \rightarrow C_3 \rightarrow \ldots \rightarrow C_n$ that is a factor of $s$. In particular (I hope I’m not using it correctly) if $B$ wasn’t reached at some point, $\ell(A) \geq n+\ell(B)$ and we get a contradiction if $n$ is too large. So the statement should be true.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It helps a lot!

Comment: And it seems that in your approach to Question 2, it seems that we need to choose $p \geq 2$ minimal such that $t \mathfrak{m}^p = \{0 \}$, instead of $p \geq 1$ ? Sorry if I've mistaken this.

Comment: @Hetong Xu: not necessarily, if $p=1$ then $q=t$ works.

Comment: I got it! Thank you! :)